# Perform jQuery UI Autocomplete onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to perform jQuery UI Autocomplete by using jQuery onclick.
My scenario : A user input its location in the input field and hit validate.

[image]

below is my code.

```
 $(".town_checker").on('click', function (e)
{
    $("#city_or_town").autocomplete(
    {
        source: function (request,
            response)
        {
            $.blockUI(
            {
                overlayCSS:
                {
                    backgroundColor: '#CACACA'
                }
            });
            $.getJSON(
                "<?php echo base_url();?>ajax/get_map_listing",
                {
                    term: extractLast(request.term)
                }, response).always(function (
                data)
            {
                $.unblockUI();
                if (data != "")
                {
                    $('.register input[type="submit"]').removeAttr(
                        'disabled');
                }
            });
        },
        search: function ()
        {
            var term = extractLast(this.value);
            if (term.length < 4)
            {
                return false;
            }
        },
        focus: function ()
        {
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: what you are doing and what you want ?????

Comment: autocomplete is not happening on Jquery onclick method

Comment: `autoccomplete` **logic** will suit only by `onKeyPress()` or `onKeyDown()` events. for validation simply use `onClick()`

Comment: you can do it. In the on click method of the button. Convert the drop down in to autocomplete anc trigger the on change event on it.